# git как изменить конфигурацию .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Как поменять содержимое файла гитигнор с удаленного репозитория?
Почему-то когда я клонирую реп там нет этого файла, хотя он создан и работает...

Comment: Как известно, что нет? Голосую за то, что он есть, но его не видно.

Comment: 1) редактировать его прям в репе (битбакет, гитхаб?) 2) включить отображение скрытых файлов и директорий

Comment: @Anatol гитлаб.

Comment: и что, там нельзя редактировать?

Comment: В *nix системе выполните `ls -a`. Или сразу `vi .gitignore`. Если у вас виндовс, то выше сказали уже.